# Updating GMSMarkers without blocking main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have MapController with GMSMapView and I need show on this map some number of GMSMarkers. I want user can interact with map without any delays, but problem is iconViews of my markers. First they must be downloaded and after I need to do some graphic calculations to get actual iconView.
So question is how to download and get from downloaded images iconViews without blocking main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Download the images in backgroundthread.After the image get downloaded then set your image to that iconView in main thread.